# Autoload Zend framework to Yii

Tags: zend-framework, yii, yii-extensions, autoloader

I tried to include Zend framework to Yii with [extension](http://yiiext.github.io/extensions/zend-autoloader-component/index.html). Problem is this:

```
Warning: include(EZendAutoloader.php): failed to open stream
```

index.php:

```
// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);

EZendAutoloader::$prefixes = array('Zend');

Yii::import("ext.yiiext.components.zendAutoloader.EZendAutoloader", true);
Yii::registerAutoloader(array("EZendAutoloader", "loadClass"), true);


$app= Yii::createWebApplication($config);
$app->run();
```

Is ok that `EZendAutoloader::$prefixes = array('Zend');` is before the import? I also tried to change the argument of Yii:import with no luck.

Comment: Why do you have an E before ZendLoader?

Comment: EZendAutoloader is the full name of the class. Anyway, as I need it quickly, I solved it out temporary like , Yii::setPathOfAlias('extensions', 'E:\full\path\to\directory\extensions'); and then Yii::import("extensions.EZendAutoloader", true); but that's not the right way how to do it.

Comment: Alias did the trick. I also have to move EZendAutoloader::$prefixes = array('Zend'); under the import

Comment: Did you place the extension into this location `dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/extensions/yiiext/components/zendAutoloader/EZendAutoloader.php'`?